# Error installing Docker on Windows server

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

I created a **new** virtual machine on `Windows Server 2019`, tried to install `Docker` and got this error. What could be the problem?

```
Docker Desktop 3.1.0
Installation failed

Component CommunityInstaller.ServiceAction failed: Failed to start service
   CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoHandleD4WPackageAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.<DoProcessAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could not be solved by installing docker via the distro, but in the end managed to install docker via the command shell

`Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server